# Parsing XML data with nested tags in Python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse XML data in the format shown below, using ElementTree:

```
<dataset>
<title>Birds of Kafiristan</title>
    <creator>
        <individualName>
            <givenName>James</givenName>
            <surName>Brooke</surName>
        </individualName>
    </creator>
    <creator>
        <organizationName>Bird Conservation Alliance</organizationName>
        <address>
            <deliveryPoint>P.O. Box 999</deliveryPoint>
            <deliveryPoint>Mailstop 1234</deliveryPoint>
            <city>Washington</city>
            <administrativeArea>DC</administrativeArea>
            <postalCode>9999</postalCode>
            <country>USA</country>
        </address>
        <phone phonetype="voice">999-999-9999 x 123</phone>
        <phone phonetype="fax">999-999-9999</phone>
        <electronicMailAddress>contact@birds.org</electronicMailAddress>
        <onlineUrl>http://www.birds.org/</onlineUrl>
    </creator>
    <contact>
        <individualName>
            <givenName>Josiah</givenName>
            <surName>Harlan</surName>
        </individualName>
    </contact>
    <pubDate>2010</pubDate>
    <abstract>
         <para>This dataset contains the results of a bird survey from Kafiristan</para>
    </abstract>
    <keywordSet>
         <keyword>birds</keyword>
         <keyword>biodiversity</keyword>
         <keyword>animal ecology</keyword>
    </keywordSet>
    <distribution>
        <online>
           <url>http://birds.org/datasets</url>
        </online>
   </distribution>
</dataset>
```

(Indeed this is just a fragment of a much larger dataset, which includes other tags, but it will suffice to ask my question.)

I want simply to get the values of the elements for each tag, using code like:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

rootElement = ET.parse("example.xml").getroot()

for subelement in rootElement:
    for subsub in subelement:
        print subsub.tag,"-->", subsub.text #, subsub.attrib, subsub.items()
        for subsubsub in subsub:
            print subsubsub.tag, "-->", subsubsub.text
```

Ruiing the code snippet above, I get the values of some elements, but not all -- indeed, I cannot get the values for nested elements (as "givenName" and "surName", which are nested inside "individualName", which in turn is nested into "creator").

Any hints or tips?

As always, thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide1

Comment: Do you want to know the text associated with _all_ tags in your document?  Or are you looking at specific tags?  In the latter case, `Element.find` might or perhaps [`Element.iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a defaultdict might be useful here:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for element in rootElement.iter():
    d[element.tag].append(element.text)
```

this will give you a mapping of tags a list of "text" associated with each tag (one item for each element with that tag in the xml.)

Comment: This has been quite helpful! Why is such great trick with a dictionary is not mentioned in the ElementTree documentation?